# Issue reproducing "Create a kml in python that has both points and lines" post

Tags: python, line, point, simplekml

I'm trying to replicate a post I came across in the link below and had an error message come up I'm a bit unsure how to resolve:
[Link to Prior Post I'm trying to replicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54769873/create-a-kml-in-python-that-has-both-points-and-lines/71620361#71620361)

I'm getting an error on the following line:

```
coord = (row[5], row[6]) # lon, lat order
```

The error message reads **IndexError: string index out of range.**  I'm calling the column numbers that have my lat and long, which is 5 & 6.  Any idea what this error message is referring to?

Here's the script I have at this point:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import simplekml
kml = simplekml.Kml()


inputfile = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/CombineKMLs_AddLabels/Data/ScopePoles.shp") 
points = []
for row in inputfile:
    coord = (row[5], row[6]) # lon, lat order
    pnt = kml.newpoint(name=row[2], coords=[coord])
    points.append(coord)    
    pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_square.png'

ls = kml.newlinestring(name='A LineString')
ls.coords = np.array(points)
ls.altitudemode = simplekml.AltitudeMode.relativetoground
ls.extrude = 1

kml.save("C:/Users/CombineKMLs_AddLabels/Data/PolesandLines.shp")
```

Comment: Need to post example of the input. If row[6] is out of range then row length is less than 6 elements. Try `print(len(row), row)` before "coord =" line.

Comment: The script is dependent on the input format, what is the content of `row`? The string index error indicates that row is just a string which has less than 3 characters, so you trying to access the third character results in an error.

Comment: kml.save() saves a .kml file not a shapefile so ".shp" in name may be confusing.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I ran that line of code you suggested and the this is the results: 8 OBJECTID
10 STR_GEOTAG
9 LINE_NAME
7 VOLTAGE
7 STR_NUM
9 LONGITUDE
8 LATITUDE
6 HEIGHT

Comment: First line is the header not a line of data.

Comment: try something like: if not row or row[0] == 'OBJECTID': continue

Comment: @CodeMonkey, thanks for pointing out the .shp file naming issue I was going to eventually run into.  Will change that to .kml!

Comment: @CodeMonkey sorry, not entirely sure where to insert that line of code

Comment: add test before `coord = (row[5], row[6]` line

Comment: Thanks @CodeMonkey, I inserted that before the coord line you mentioned and the error code reads IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Need to debug it. `print(len(row), row)` if length value < 6 then that is the issue causing error.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Here's what I am getting: for row in inputfile:
    if not row or row[0] == 'OBJECTID': continue
    print(len(row), row)
    coord = (row[5], row[6]) # lon, lat order 8 OBJECTID
10 STR_GEOTAG
9 LINE_NAME
7 VOLTAGE
7 STR_NUM
9 LONGITUDE
8 LATITUDE
6 HEIGHT

Comment: try: if not row or row[0].startswith('OBJECTID'): continue

Comment: @CodeMonkey I used that after the for row in inputfile line but seems to be the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.iterrows()` to iterate over the data frame and `df.loc[index, 'geometry']` to access the point.

```python
import geopandas as gpd
import simplekml

kml = simplekml.Kml()

df = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/CombineKMLs_AddLabels/Data/ScopePoles.shp")

points = []
for index, poi in df.iterrows():
  pt = df.loc[index, 'geometry']
  coord = (pt.x, pt.y)
  pnt = kml.newpoint(name=index, coords=[coord])
  points.append(coord)
  pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_square.png'

ls = kml.newlinestring(name='A LineString', coords=points)

kml.save('PolesandLines.kml')
```

Comment: thanks for the follow up for this question.  It looks as if this will process through the code without an error.  The results show all the points and a line connecting all the points.  How would I need to edit this further to have the line and points break into individual clusters based on a unique name found in each of line and point shapefiles?  The end result would be one line assigned to numerous points, then another line assigned to numerous points, for all lines in the original shapefile.

Comment: @Geno - Sounds like the answer above solves your original question and this should be a new question. For that you could add a check as first line in for loop to test with logic for name to create a new cluster then create a new line and reset `points = []` to start a new line, etc.